# Trying to load grunticons with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm using the gem will_paginate and trying to replace the Previous and Next text with grunticon icons. It works when the page loads, however, when I click to load the next page the span element is inserted, the icons don't show, and none of the svg data loads.

I'm at a loss as to why this is giving me such an issue. Thanks for any insight you can provide.

My jQuery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.pagination .previous_page').html('<span class="icon-chevron-left" data-grunticon-embed></span>');
  $('.pagination .next_page').html('<span class="icon-chevron-right" data-grunticon-embed></span>');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="pagination">
  <a class="previous_page" rel="prev start" href="/promotion/show/52671?page=1">
    <!--jQuery inserts span here-->
    <span class="icon-chevron-left" data-grunticon-embed></span>
  </a> 
  <a rel="prev start" href="/promotion/show/52671?page=1">1</a> 
  <em class="current">2</em> 
  <a rel="next" href="/promotion/show/52671?page=3">3</a> 
  <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/promotion/show/52671?page=3">
    <!--jQuery inserts span here-->
    <span class="icon-chevron-right" data-grunticon-embed></span>
  </a>
</div>
```